# Disabling auto-brightness with dual monitors

Tags: macbook-pro, display, system-settings, auto-brightness

I have a MacBook Pro (14-inch, 2021) connected to an external monitor.

I've disabled 'auto-brightness' but the screen keeps dimming by itself. I've tried setting it in my preferences both with and without the external monitor connected.

Am I doing something wrong?

[image]

Comment: Are you running the MBP off the battery? There's a setting to reduce screen brightness when on the battery in the Energy prefs.

Comment: @benwiggy If you put that as the answer it'll be easier to find than in comments. Please do so so the question can be considered answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As well as the settings in Display preferences, there are options in the Energy preference pane to reduce the Brightness when on battery.